# Returning a value from within a promise

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I have a service that injects a service. The child service connects to the facebook api and is suppose to return the login status of the user to the parent service. The problem I am facing is this fb api call uses a promise and I am trying to execute some logic in the parent service based on the value of the child service function call. What would be the correct way of doing this?

This is what I tried:

facebook.service.ts

Note, the below code successfully connects to the facebook api and outputs "connected" as it should**

```
checkLoginStatus() {
        this.FB.getLoginStatus( (response) => {
            console.log(response.status); //outputs "connected"
        });

}
```

However, I am trying to return the value contained within the promise's response to the parent service, so I modified the code as follows... and getting the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLoginStatus' of undefined
```

facebook.service.ts

```
 FB:any;

    constructor() {
        facebook().then((FB) => {
            // Initialize SDK
            FB.init({
                appId      : '1111111111111111',
                cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                                    // the session
                xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
                version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.5
            });

            this.FB = FB;

        });
    }

    checkLoginStatus() {
        this.FB.getLoginStatus( (response) => {
           return response.status; //"connected"
        });
    }
```

home.service.ts

```
constructor(@Inject(FacebookService) private fb:FacebookService) {
    this.authenticateFacebook();
}

authenticateFacebook() {
    this.fb.checkLoginStatus().then( (response) => {
        console.log(response); //should output connected
    });
}
```

Comment: If nothing is printed, it's probably that the callback passed to this.FB.getLoginStatus() is never executed. Probably because the getLoginStatus() call failed. It probably expects a second callback in case of error. Where is the documentation for this `FB.getLoginStatus()` method?

Comment: @JBNizet, getLoginStatus is successful and returning "connected"

Comment: What do you mean by "returning". You're not using the value returned by `this.FB.getLoginStatus()`. You're passing a callback instead. And how do you know what it returns (or passes to your callback), since nothing is printed? Again, what is the documentation for FB.getLoginStatus()? What you pointed to just allows loading the facebook library. It doesn't document the method  FB.getLoginStatus().

Comment: Posted the documentation. I know what it returns b/c I logged the response to console (see edited code). The fact is, `getLoginStatus` contains a string in the response, signifying successful authentication, which I am trying to return to the parent service.

Comment: This is the FB documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

Comment: Ah, so the problem is not that nothing is printed. The problem is that you're getting an error. this.FB is undefined, as the error clearly shows. Post the code initializing this.FB, because that's (also) where the problem is.

Comment: updated the code.

Answer (score -1):

At the time where you're calling your service, `this.FB` is still undefined, as the error shows. That's because the initialization itself is asynchronous: facebook() loads the library, and only when it's loaded, `this.FB` is initialized. You just need to wait for this initialization to be done before using `this.FB`. The fix is relatively simple though:

```
private fbPromise: Promise<any>;

constructor() {
    this.fbPromise = facebook().then((FB) => {
        // Initialize SDK
        FB.init({
            appId      : '1111111111111111',
            cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                                // the session
            xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
            version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.5
        });

        return FB;
    });
}

private authenticateFacebook(FB): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        FB.getLoginStatus(response => resolve(response));
    });
}

checkLoginStatus(): Promise<string> {
    return this.fbPromise
               .then(FB => this.authenticateFacebook(FB))
               .then(response => response.status);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, you're completely ignoring the fact the two functions are in different files and not really addressing the actual problem. The goal is to output the login status in `home.service.ts`. Basically,  `checkLoginStatus()` is in a separate file and I am trying to prevent the  need for `this.fbPromise` within the `home.service.ts` file... read the original from start to finish, it should make sense.

Comment: Anchovy I am not sure what you are asking anymore.

Comment: @Piotr, its really quite simple, read the original post. In the topmost, `facebook.service.ts` code snippet, "connected" is being logged to console. Therefore, all communication with the Facebook API is successful. Now, instead of logging this string to console, the goal is simply to return the "connected" string to the parent service within `home.service.ts`. The above implementation doesn't help accomplish this in any way.

Comment: The only way you can do what you are trying to achieve is to pass a reference to the service you want to call into the facebook service so when it is initd you can execute a function on it (or interface) or you can use observable instead of promises, and then you can listen to the observable for changes when facebook is "connected" to fire something in your second service.

Comment: A snippet of what you mean would be appreciated.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend Inject the service where this checkLoginStatus function (in my answer) is defined wherever you want, and do `myService.checkLoginStatus().then(status => console.log(status))`. I'm not ignoring anything. I just know how promises work, but you don't seem to understand them. The fact that the code is in two files is completely irrelevant. A promise is a promise is a promise, wherever it comes from.

Answer (score -2):

Just wrap it in your own promise which you can return and in the resolve value you can specify a return value.

```
public authenticateFacebook(): Promise<any> {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           this.fb.checkLoginStatus().then( response => {
                console.log(response); //should output connected
                resolve(response);
            });
        });

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Piotr. Although this answer looks promising, this did not work for me... still no errors.

Comment: This will def work - i am using it. Not with facebook but as a general principle to return values.

Comment: Try add a reject(value) and see if there are any errors, maybe checkLoginstatus throws an error when there is an error that is why resolve response is not working.

Comment: Please see updated code, now getting a new error `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLoginStatus' of undefined` that I was not getting before wrapping with my own promise

Comment: try change response => to (response) => otherwise maybe its the way you are injecting it i am not familiar with that @injection syntax.

Comment: Adding the parens made no difference. The injection syntax is valid. Updated the code once again. Still getting the same error.

Comment: this.FB should not be able to work because capital FB is not declared anywhere it should be little fb?

Comment: This is an anti-pattern. Chaining should be used: `return this.fb.checkLoginStatus().then( response => {
                console.log(response); 
                return response;
            });`

Comment: FB *is* declared / initialized in the construct, if it wasnt, it would never return "connected"... the facebook service is returning "connected", but I am not able to access this value in the parent service...

Comment: Will response be a promise? I am not sure.